# div contents change position

Tags: html, css

I have a header div which is absolute so I want to make it fixed, but if I do that the contents inside starts changing position on resizing window. What trick can I use to achieve a fixed header div  which do not move contents on window resize ?
Below is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<head>
<title>Client  </title>

<style type="text/css">
.heading {position:fixed; visibility:show; width:100%;  left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index:3;
 border-bottom:5px solid #ccc; } 
 header{
 position:absolute;
     width: 100%;
    height: 60px !important;
    z-index:7;
    top: 0px;
}

/*My div position*/
.positioning-container{position:relative; 
width:1000px;  margin:0 auto 0 auto;
 black solid; padding:0px;

   padding:60px 0 30px 0; 
  border-bottom:0px; padding:0px;
 background:#eee;}

.inner-container{position:relative; 
 background:#fff; padding:0px;
   padding:60px 0 30px 0; }
/*My div position*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="positioning-container">
<div class="inner-container" align = "center">
<header>
<div class= "heading" style="width:100% ; height:50px; background-color:#00A5C6">
<table id ="headertable" align="left"><tr><td>
<a href="index.php"><h2 class= "logo">Client Review</h2><td>&nbsp;</td></a></td><td>
<label>Search</label><input typ= "text"></td>
<td><a href="index.php" class="button middle">search</a></td>
<td><a href="login.php" class="button middle">Login</a></td>
<td><a href="register.php" class="button middle">Add Client</a></td>
<td><a href="logout.php" class="button middle">Logout</a></td>
<td align="left" class="profile"><img src="bhubezi/images/logos/nopic.png" width="50" 

height="40"></td>

</tr>
</table>
</div>
</header>
<div class="content">
content
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the content inside it they will still move

Comment: Hey Humphrey , resizing will always make the content move if it wont, than it will go out of div or something else might happen  . Content needs to be rearranged when resizing and to make it readable and properly arranged , you have to position things keeping resizing in your mind ,if you want to cater lot of people

Comment: Please show me how I can solve this all I want is a fixed header like for facebook and wen I resize I do not get contents change position

Comment: Friend resizing will always make the content flow , until and unless u make it fixed width and non responsive .

Comment: A responsive layout is all you need .. creating a jsfiddle for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give your .heading class a minimum width.

so on your css add something like

```
min-width:700px;
```

on your .heading styles